# How quickly can new US tax code be implemented?

Tags: united-states, taxes

The question "[Can Trump implement his tax reform](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11834/can-trump-really-implement-his-tax-reform)" is similar, but not quite the same as my question.

I would like to know the typical time it takes between the new president inauguration and the tax year of the new code.

[image: Legislative history of Reagan's tax reform bill]

It seems that Reagan, elected in 1980, passed his tax reform within 7 months of swearing in. Further reading shows that bits of it were retroactive to 1981.

Is this fast turnaround typical?

Comment: Your subject asks "how quickly", implying "what's the fastest possible, in theory", whereas your body asks "is this typical", implying averages in past practice. Which one are you actually asking?

Comment: I'd expect the answer to comprise both aspects. Something like "Reagan set a record, the typical time from inauguration to passing is....."

Comment: So do you care about theoretically fastest, or merely actually achieved record? The former may very well be less (iirc, in 1981, Reagan was dealing with opposing Congress?)

Comment: At my home stack, Money.SE, there are times we respond that a question is really two and suggest an edit and second question. Here, I think the reverse is true. Both answers can be given in a long sentence, and if I spilt into 2, I'd expect one gets closed as a duplicate of the other. And, my question avoids opinion, I'm not actually asking if Trump can push through quickly, just how fast it could be done, logistically.

Comment: I agree, it's definitely objective. I'm just sure that depending on whether you want theoretically possible record, or actual past record, the answer will be different, probably drastically.

Comment: I would assume it varies far too much; it depends at least on the size of Congress majorities and the complexity of the bill(s) themselves. Reagan adopted a far simpler (and far smaller) economy, so any large changes would be much harder to pull off quickly today.

Comment: The Republicans have a Congressional majority. And most of the tax changes appear to be tweaks, not "large" changes. Although, the plan itself appears a moving target.

Comment: Remember that retroactive taxes themselves are legal. So, in theory, the next President could pass a tax that applies to this year or even previous years.